# MSSQL Foreign Key Relationship and Null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm having problems adding a foreign key to an existing table where the foreign key can be null.

Say I have a user table and a data table. The data table already has a working foreign key on the "createdBy" colum to the user table ID column. I've just added a second column to the data table "EditedBy" that allows for null values (meaning the data record hasn't been edited). So all the existing records have NULL as the value for this column.

I am trying to make a foreign key between Data.EditedBy and User.Id, but when I try to apply it, I get the following error.

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Data_User_EditedBy". The conflict occurred in database "Test", table "dbo.User", column 'Id'.

It seems like its having a problem with the NULL values in the data table, but NULL is an acceptable value for a foreign key.

What am I missing?

UPDATE: 
Full statement is as follows

```
USE [Test]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Data]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Data_User_EditedBy] FOREIGN KEY([Id])
REFERENCES [dbo].[User] ([Id])
GO
```

Comment: show the full alter statement, and the relevant DDL for the two tables...

Comment: That generally means you have a value in the EditedBy column that has no matching value in User.Id. Be careful here. When you make this kind of foreign key to a User table you have to either set the foreign key values to NULL OR you cannot ever delete a User.

Comment: Sean, that's what I've been finding online so far. But I just created the EditedBy column right before trying to apply the foreign key, so every record present has a NULL value currently. And as far as deleting users, I never delete a record. I have a delete flag so that user accounts can be recovered and so that I can avoid the very issue you're describing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I feel like an idiot. I was using Management studio to create the relationship, and after I posted the equivalent alter statement (which didn't work either), I realized I was trying to make a foreign key between the ID field of [data] and the ID field of [user].

Obviously that wont work.

I fixed the statement to use the correct field in the [data] table and all is well.

Comment: You can accept your own answer to show others that your question has a satisfactory answer.